# How to redirect multiprocessing pool function

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a tkinter text widget and I want to redirect sys.stdout to the text widget. I fulfilled this function partly, but I face problem with multiprocessing.

Following is a python 3 toy you can play with,

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Pool

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400+30+30')

textArea = tk.Text(root, bg='gray', width=70, height=20)
textArea.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='click me', command=lambda: print('Dont touch\n me!')).pack()

class redirectStd():
    def __init__(self, textWidget):
        self.textBoard = textWidget
        self.flush = sys.stdout.flush
    def write(self, msg):
        self.textBoard.insert('end', msg)

sys.stdout = redirectStd(textArea)
sys.stderr = redirectStd(textArea)

def f(x):
    print('calculate:', x, '** 2')
    return x ** 2

def testParallel():
    print('start testing')
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        res = p.map(f, [1, 4, 0, 7, 3, 5])
        print(res)

tk.Button(root, text='test multiprocessing', command=testParallel).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will run correctly. However, the print in `def f(x)` won't print anything in the text widget.

If comment `self.flush = sys.stdout.flush` in the `class redirectStd` block, will cause error which complains **flush** undefined in **redirectStd**. At this stage, I haven't found out how to define a **flush** method for **redirectStd**. The full error message is

```
start testing
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 28, in testParallel
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 168, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 233, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/zsf/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 17, in __init__
    sys.stdout.flush()
AttributeError: 'redirectStd' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

Can anyone provide a hint of solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Rethink your Approach, use some _**IPC**_ instead of Redirections. Your Base Problem are `f` is a separate Process with his own `Stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are using multi threading might have issue, check out the documentation below

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

I worked out your problem in a slightly different way, hope this helps

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Pool


class redirectStd():
    def __init__(self, textWidget):
    self.textBoard = textWidget
    #self.flush = sys.stdout.flush
def write(self, msg):
    self.textBoard.insert('end', msg)

def f(x):
    print('calculate:', x, '** 2')
    return x ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x400+30+30')

    textArea = tk.Text(root, bg='gray', width=70, height=20)
    textArea.pack()
    tk.Button(root, text='click me', command=lambda: print('Dont touch\n me!')).pack()

    sys.stdout = redirectStd(textArea)
    sys.stderr = redirectStd(textArea)

    def testParallel():
        p = Pool(5)
        print(p.map(f, [10, 2, 3]))

    tk.Button(root, text='test multiprocessing', command=testParallel).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It still causes that error. I have to uncomment `#self.flush = sys.stdout.flush` to get it run correctly. However, the `print('calculate: ', x, '** 2')` print nothing. Do you have any further advice? BTW, I test this on macOS 10.12.6